# How do I display content on slideshows?

Tags: javascript

I am using the [Jssor Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/jssor) module. My slider works, but the content type *Jssor slider*, where text is displayed on images, is not working on Drupal 8.

I want to display content on slideshows like shown on 
http://www.jssor.com/demos/content-slider.slider. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the module and tested.It works. Seems you missed the pre-configured **view** provided by this module.

You can find it at `http://www.example.com/jssor_jssor`. Find the **jssor** views in the view list. You can do slider settings in the view itself.

Seems you've selected 'Content' instead of Jssor in view. If you select 'content' it display normal slider. So in order to display text on slider make sure to add **Jssor** in **show** under FORMAT options.

[image]